# Check user score is lowest score or not

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that represent user game score.User have a team . I have need to check user total game score is lowest from other team member score or not.

my table

```
id   user_id   game_id   team_id  score
1      31        56        40      0
2      31        56        40      9
4      24        56        40      0
5      24        56        40      5
7      24        56        40      14
10     24        57        45      3
```

i am trying with this query but not work

```
SELECT * FROM score WHERE score = ( SELECT MIN(score) FROM score)
 and game_id=56 and team_id=40 and user_id=31 GROUP BY user_id
```

here

user 31 total score of game_id 56 and team_id 40 is 9
user 24 total score of game_id 56 and team_id 40 is 19

so if i query with user_id 24 then no row affected

Comment: Out of the two users, do you want to figure out who has the lowest score for game 56?

Comment: so what do you do if there's a tie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go.

This will tell you who had the lowest combined score for game 56.

```
SELECT game_id, team_id, user_id, total_score FROM (
    SELECT game_id, team_id, user_id, sum(score) AS total_score 
    FROM score 
    GROUP BY game_id,team_id, user_id
) final_scores
WHERE game_id=56
ORDER BY total_score limit 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

To get a user's total score for a game while on a particular team you need to group by `user_id`, `game_id` and `team_id` (your data shows a user can have multiple records -- and possibly teams, depending on your data model, but you remove the `AND` clause if desired -- for a single game):

```
SELECT user_id, total_score
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(score) as total_score, user_id, team_id, game_id
    FROM score
    WHERE game_id = 56
    AND team_id = 40
    GROUP BY user_id, game_id, team_id
) s
WHERE s.total_score = MIN(s.total_score)
```

I placed the `WHERE` clause inside of the table expression so the database has less rows to sum.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
SELECT * FROM score WHERE score > ( SELECT MIN(score) FROM score)

 and game_id=56 and team_id=40 and user_id=31 GROUP BY user_id
```

this will give output user total game score is lowest from other team member